# Update Objects and reset the isDirty-flag (ember-data 1.0 beta.2)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With former versions of ember-data I could bring a modified model back to clear-state by calling:

user.transitionTo('loaded.saved')

Is there a way to do this in version 1.0beta.2? The main reason is to suppress any server requests when saying

user.save()

[Edit] - I didn't explicitly mention, that my intention was to keep the modified values, just resetting the dirty-state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I really wanted to do is updating some fields of a record w/o setting the dirty flag.

store.update(type, hash)

here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/09/04/ember-data-1-0-beta-2-released.html
does right that.

Answer (score 0):

I responded over at Discourse, too, but for the sake of completeness:

`user.rollback()` does what you aim to do, judging from the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js#L251-253).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question, sorry for being somewhat unclear. The discussion at Discourse: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/update-objects-and-reset-the-isdirty-flag-ember-data-1-0-beta-2/2518/5